# Parity check matrix to generator matrix

Tags: coding-theory

Does anyone know how to go from a parity check matrix $H$ to a generator matrix ($GH^T = 0$) **without** having either in standard form? Meaning that the order of row/columns stay the same (i.e. the 'bits' stay in the same place as opposed to putting the matrix in standard form because this might interchange some columns)

(this might be simple but it's not clear to me how to do it)

EDIT: Is this $G$ just the orthogonal complement of $H$?

Thanks :)

Comment: You may work with the reduced row echelon form instead of the standard form. This avoids interchanging columns. See for example http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/419/ker.im.html#:~:text=To%20find%20the%20kernel%20of,%3D%200%20or%20BX%20%3D%200.

Comment: Yes! this solves it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered to some satisfaction in the comment by [Andreas Lenz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/533869/andreas-lenz), as written by the poster in another comment.

From the comments:

"You may work with the reduced row echelon form instead of the standard form. This avoids interchanging columns. See for example [https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/419/ker.im.html"](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ehochster/419/ker.im.html%22)